# Let $f: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ with characteristic polynomial $-\lambda(\lambda-3)^2$ and $f(1,0,0)=(1,0,-1)$ and $f(0,1,0)=(2,3,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $f: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ be a diagonalizable endomorphism with characteristic polynomial $-\lambda(\lambda-3)^2$ such that 
$f(1,0,0)=(1,0,-1)$ and $f(0,1,0)=(2,3,1)$. Given these data, how can I find the explicit expession on $f(x,y,z)$ and a basis of $\mathbb{R^3}$ of eigenvectors of $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that the matrix of the endomorphism is
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & a \\
0 & 3 & b \\
-1 & 1 & c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some $a,b,c$. Elimination gives
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & a \\
0 & 3 & b \\
0 & 3 & c+a
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and, since we know that the rank must be $2$, we can conclude that $b=c+a$. We also know that $3$ is an eigenvalue of $f$ with multiplicity $2$, so the rank of $A-3I$ must be $1$ (because $A$ is supposed to be diagonalizable):
$$
A-3I=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 2 & a \\
0 & 0 & a+c \\
-1 & 1 & c-3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Let's do elimination again:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 2 & a \\
0 & 0 & a+c \\
-1 & 1 & c-3
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & -a/2 \\
0 & 0 & a+c \\
-1 & 1 & c-3
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & -a/2 \\
0 & 0 & a+c \\
0 & 0 & c-3-a/2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Can you say what the conclusion is?

Comment: Could you also use $tr(A)=4+c=6$, so $c=2$?

Comment: @user84413 Of course, but that gives just one condition and you need three, so computing the rank of $A-3I$ is necessary anyway. Consider also that you need to find eigenvectors, so with the matrices $A$ and $A-3I$ in row echelon form you almost have them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I thought maybe that would shorten the process, but I guess it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, professor. But could you solve this without using elimination (we've not studied it)? Also, can you explicit why "we know that the rank must be 2"?

Comment: @user62029 Elimination is just one way to solve a system or to compute the rank. We know that the rank must be $2$ because $0$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $1$.